# Combining COUNT and RANK - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank

What I need to select is total number of trips made by every 'id_customer' from table user and their id, dispatch_seconds, and distance for first order. id_customer, customer_id, and order_id are strings.

It should looks like this

```
+------+--------+------------+--------------------------+------------------+
|  id  | count  | #1order id | #1order dispatch seconds | #1order distance |
+------+--------+------------+--------------------------+------------------+
| 1ar5 |      3 | 4r56       |                        1 |              500 |
| 2et7 |      2 | dc1f       |                        5 |              100 |
+------+--------+------------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

Cheers!

Original post was edited as during discussion S-man helped me to find exact problem solution. Solution by S-man https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e16aa6008990107e55a26d05b10b02b5

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query includes product specific functionality.)

Comment: Which database? SQL is language, but individual databases implement some portions of it differently, especially when it comes to what aggregate and analytic functions are available.

Comment: Is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e16aa6008990107e55a26d05b10b02b5)

```
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    order_id,
    order_timestamp,
    dispatch_seconds,
    distance
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        count(*) over (partition by customer_id),    -- A
        first_value(order_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_timestamp) -- B
    FROM orders
)s

WHERE order_id = first_value -- C
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

A window function which gets the total record count per user

B window function which orders all records per user by timestamp and gives the first `order_id` of the corresponding user. Using `first_value` instead of `min` has one benefit: Maybe it could be possible that your order IDs are not really increasing by timestamp (maybe two orders come in simultaneously or your order IDs are not sequential increasing but some sort of hash)

--> both are new columns

C now get all columns where the "first_value" (aka the first `order_id` by timestamp)  equals the `order_id` of the current row. This gives all rows with the first order by user.

Result:

```
customer_id  count  order_id  order_timestamp      dispatch_seconds  distance  
-----------  -----  --------  -------------------  ----------------  --------  
1ar5         3      4r56      2018-08-16 17:24:00  1                 500       
2et7         2      dc1f      2018-08-15 01:24:00  5                 100
```

Note that in these test data the order "dc1f" of user "2et7" has a smaller timestamp but comes later in the rows. It is not the first occurrence of the user in the table but nevertheless the one with the earliest order. This should demonstrate the case `first_value` vs. `min` as described above.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've checked all solutions placed by others and each of them results in different data :p What if I want to show amount spend for first order id, and time which took to deliver this order?

What I can't understand at all is fact that after adding whole line (first_vale(amount_spend) OVER(the same conditionswhat above) it shows other order COUNT than before. After adding another line with delivery time results are different than previous ones as well

Comment: Maybe you could provide a more detailed/larger data set. It's hard to discuss issues without seeing the related data.

Comment: I've tried to create table in dbfiddle but I'm a newbie but hope it's clear. What I need to select is total number of trips made by every 'id_customer' from table user and their id, dispatch_seconds, and distance for first order. id_customer, customer_id, and order_id are strings.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3dc4a83d235aa2e8188329844364ab58

Comment: I updated your db fiddle and added some dummy data to the int columns because you provided none of them. By adding these int columns you changed the problem a little bit so a slighty more complicate query results. Please update this in your question.

Comment: @snowboi updated the whole text because of your new data.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.customer_id, COUNT(*)
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN o.order_id END) as first_order_id
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_timestamp ASC) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
     ) o
GROUP BY o.customer_id;
```

Your `JOIN` is not necessary for this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select distinct customer_id, 
       count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as no_of_order
       min(order_id) over (partition by customer_id order by order_timestamp) as first_order_id
from orders o;
```

Comment: If the order number is not increasing by time (may something random) `first_value` should be better then `min`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many mistakes in your original query, your rank isn't partitioned, the order by clause seems incorrect, you filter out all but one "random" order, then apply the count, the list goes on.

Something like this seems closer to what you seem to want?

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    order_count,
    order_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.customer_id,
        a.order_count,
        a.order_id,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.order_id, a.customer_id ORDER BY a.order_count DESC) AS rank_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            order_id,
            COUNT(*) AS order_count
        FROM 
            orders
        GROUP BY
            customer_id,
            order_id) a) b
WHERE 
    b.rank_id = 1;
```